# Can we create an application using code first approach and later maintenance of same application using database first approach?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If a web-application is created with Code First Approach, then during maintenance can we modify it using Database First Approach ? Or do we have to stick to code first approach forever?
I am a beginner , please apologize if it is very simple question.

Comment: Can someone please help or point me in right direction with this question.

Comment: From your question it seems you are talking about using Entity Framework in MVC application. In code first approach you write your Entities and DbContext class yourself first and then run migration to create database tables. Later if you use database first approach, it will create separate DbContext class and Entities, so your already written code will not automatically use these entities.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to convert your code-first classes into database-first classes. You need to delete Models, DBContext and the Connection String  and then recreate them with EF Designer (using Database First to create Entity Data Model).